# How to save memory when storing a lot of 'Entry' in a map in java?

Tags: java, hashmap

I want to store 1*10^8 Objects in a map for searching. When my program start, it will read and store these objects in a map. After reading is end, this map never be updated util program is dead. I don't want jvm to abandon any of them. I learn that `HashMap` will waste many memory , is there any type of map can store so much objects and save memory?

and I know that jvm will scan these objects, it waste time. how to avid this?
Sorry, The situation is that: I am writing a bolt with apache storm. I want to read data from databases. when a bolt is processing a tuple, I need to calculate with the data in databases. For performance of program I have to store them in memory. I know jvm is not good at managing a lot of memory, So maybe I should to try koloboke?

Comment: Why do you have to store them in a HashMap? What kind of Objects are you dealing with? Please add more context.

Comment: This sounds like you probably should use a database.

Comment: What amount of memory is ok and how much is used?

Comment: @Herr Derb,It is too slow.

Comment: @Z.Lun I hardly believe this.

Comment: @Mister Henson I only tryed 4x10^7 ，It cost about 5-10g...I can not estimate that..

Comment: If you could use map of primitive types, you could try trove4j or something

Comment: Another approach is to use sorted ArrayList instead of hashmap and use binary search to locate data.

Comment: @kan   key is a string, value is a user-defined class of object. I searched about trove4j, Maybe trove4j do not support this..

Comment: Java G1 gc available in recent versions is much designed for large heaps, try it too

Comment: Keeping data in memory not always necessary mean better performance - have you measured the effect? The point is - it is not easy question to answer as it depends heavily on your unique conditions. You should try different options and see which one works for you better. And start with performance tests first!

Comment: @kan  java version is 8u50. I can not decide to update this. Now I still use CMS... every machine have  128 or 256 GB memory. So keeping all data in memory is nothing serious..and storing part of data is hard to code .Memory is enough, I just want to save some.

Comment: G1 is availiable since java 7u4, so you should have it, so try.

Comment: See http://java-performance.info/hashmap-overview-jdk-fastutil-goldman-sachs-hppc-koloboke-trove-january-2015/ - compared to koloboke and others, the plain old JDK HashMap is the most efficient for mostly read-only usage of large entries where both key and value are Objects. Try tuning the `loadFactor` constructor argument to achieve optimum performance vs memory usage balance.

Comment: It all depends on what type of calculation you need to do with the tuple and the map. I guess you need the map to perform some aggregate calculation based on the tuple?

Answer (score 3):

[`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) need to allocate array of sufficient size in order to minimize hash collisions - it can happen that two or more objects that are not equal have the same hash code - probability of such situation depends on quality of hash function. Collisions are resolved by techniques such as *linear probing*, which stores entry at next `(hash + i) mod length` index that is not occupied, *quadratic probing* which stores entry at next `(hash + i^k) mod length` index that is not occupied, `separate chaining` which stores linked list of entries at each bucket. Collision probability is decreased by increasing length of backing array, thus **memory wasting**.

However, you can use [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) which stores entries in tree structure that creates only such a number of nodes that is equal to number of entries i. e. **efficient memory usage**.

Note, there is a difference in complexity of *get*, *put*, *remove* operations. [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) has complexity `O(1)`, while [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) has complexity `O(log n)`.

Suppose you want to get an entry from map of size 100 000 000, then in worst case (element to be found is leaf i. e. is located at the last level of the tree), path that need to be passed down the tree has length log(100 000 000) = 8.

Comment: Thanks. I will try TreeMap, if not lost many performance,I'll use it always.

Comment: TreeMap is worse than ArrayList+binarySearch for usecase when map is  never be updated.

Comment: @kan in which terms? Tree-based structures are already using binary search technique so the complexity is the same (assuming balanced tree which is standard), the only benefit of using sorted array/arrayList + binary search is lower memory consumption as there is no need for creating entry wrappers - nodes. By using an array you can not create mapping i. e.  you can not store element under specified key, which seems the OP is doing. Moreover, binary search in array accept object to be searched as argument and returns it's index - again this seems not to be what OP wants.

Comment: @matoni Tree structure is not flat, has more reference indirections, so less memory cache friendly and GC has more difficult structure to navigate. And yes, requires more memory for each element (which is what OP is fighting against), I even suspect that TreeMap could take more space than tuned HashMap. You not necessary need to store element by a key, this is what binarySearch for - search in the ordered list by the key to match.

Comment: @kan matoni      binary-search+sorted arraylist can solve this problem. but it is usually used when key is a integer or long.. I use a key of String...but I will try. Use TreeMap don't need any other code. In addition,I will also try use HashMap with specified size. I will tell you both the result.SO don't quarrel.

Comment: @Z.Lun What's difference between integer or String? Elements in the array should just be sorted by the key.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am back.
In first I used about 30g to store about 5x10^7 key-value entry.. but gc is not stable.I make a mistake about using string to store double, it is bigger than double in memory and a char is 16bit in java ..after I changed this mistake, gc is better..but not enough. Finally I used 'filedb' in mapdb to fix this.